# Cannot call methods on varbinary using nettopologysuite

Tags: c#, linq, nettopologysuite

I try to request my db with efcore and linq but I have the error: Cannot call methods on varbinary.

I can't sort it out.

The code is:

```
places
.Where(p => p.Place.Location != null && p.Place.Location.Distance(currentLocation)<=input.Radius)
.OrderBy(p => currentLocation.Distance(p.Place.Location));
```

CurrentLocation is:

```
currentLocation = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(input.Place.Latitude, input.Place.Longitude)
            {
                SRID = 4326
            };
```

If I do this it works. It seems it's the order by which not works.

```
places = places.Where(p => p.Place.Location != null && p.Place.Location.Distance(currentLocation) <= input.Radius);
// .OrderBy(p => currentLocation.Distance(p.Place.Location));
```

And input.radius is an integer.

Can you help pleasE?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed my issue by inverting the call in orderby

This code below works for anybody who has the issue

```
places = places.Where(p => p.Place.Location != null && p.Place.Location.Distance(currentLocation) <= input.Radius)
.OrderBy(p => p.Place.Location.Distance(currentLocation));
```

Comment: Had the same problem in my Where statement, this worked for me, thanks!